# how to pass dynamic values for time in the cmd

Tags: ruby

I have already tried this, and it returns the present time,

```
puts "Enter the time"
a = Time.now
p a.strftime('%I:%M %P')
```

but it has to return the time dynamically i.e., if I pass some random time in the terminal it has to print the time in 24hr format

Comment: It sounds like you need to add a `gets` and a `Time.parse`, from here...

Comment: There are many ways, depending in what form you have the current time (data type, timezone, ....). Have a look at the [definition of the Time class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think i got the answer for that question

```
require 'time'
puts "Enter the time"
a = gets.chomp
p Time.parse(":#{a}").strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```